# XSLT multiple conditions with "contains"

Tags: xslt

I am a newcomer to XSLT technologies and I have hit a wall.

I need to filter (and copy) all nodes whose name contains "stringA" and who is also a child of a node whose name contains "stringB".

I am having trouble with `multiple conditions`.

I didnt find any thread related to my issue.

If anyone could direct me to something relevant or explain it that would be much appreciated.

```
<x>
<a>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
</a>

<b>
    <a>4</a>
    <b>5</b>
    <c>6</c>
</b>

<c>
    <a>7</a>
    <b>8</b>
    <c>9</c>
</c>
```

I need to copy all nodes whose name contains "c" and whose ancestor node contains "b". Value of 6 in this example.

Comment: i have tried using "ancestor axis" but i cant seem to make it work.

Comment: Please post some sample XML showing your particular situation.  Without that, we're all just guessing.

Comment: I have made the required change in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

```
//*[contains(name(),'stringB')]/*[contains(name(),'stringA')]
```

Comment: Yes, although my problem is testing my parent node name.

Comment: OK, changed to test the parent node name.